# Visual Studio fot Mac Creating Android build for iOS Target when Archived

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-mac

I have been working on a Xamarin app. Recently whenever I try to create a build, the Visual Studio for Mac is incorrectly targetting tee platforms.

It is creating Android build every time I use Build -> Archive All or Build -> Archive for Publishing.

Sometimes the reverse is happening. That is, creating iOS archive instead of Android.

I am selecting the project and platform correctly.

If you have encountered similar issue please suggest a solution.

The version of Visual Studio at the time of this is **Visual Studio for Mac 2019 8.3.11 (build 1).**

Comment: Hi , do u have a try with creating a new project to check whether can work .If also not , you can submit it [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues) in GitHub .